# SQL Server column names contain question marks instead of Russian characters

Tags: php, sql-server, encoding, utf-8, yii2

I am new to sql server and know little about encoding. I use PHP 7, Yii2 for my project.

Current db configuration is:

```
'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
'dsn' => 
'sqlsrv:Server=172.16.30.22,1433;Database=DEV_PM_TOOLS;ConnectionPooling=0',
'charset' => 'utf8',
```

When I try to create a pivot table (convert distinct row values to column names) my query returns question marks instead of Russian characters (The `[ПТО0004]` column in incorrectly encoded.). And the exception message is `Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded.`:

```
0 => [
    'ItemKey' => '990'
    'ItemNo' => 'BO 3397118991'
    'CompanyKey' => '15'
    'Description' => 'Щітка склоочисника'
    'SearchDescription' => 'К-Т БЕСКАРКАСНЫЙ AEROTWIN 650/600 MM A991S RETROOFIT'
    'TopCode' => 'C'
    'ResponsibleBrandAnalyst' => 'EES0947'
    'ResponsibleBrandManager' => 'EES0947'
    'Grp' => 'СТЕКЛООЧИСТИТЕЛЬ'
    'SubGrp' => 'ЩЕТКИ СТЕКЛООЧЕСТИТЕЛЯ'
    'Brand' => 'BOSCH'
    'V00214' => null
    '���0004' => '14.2953'
    'PrimeCost' => '14.8400'
    'UnitPriceD3' => '16.516300'
    'AnnualSalesQuantityBase' => '63.0000'
    'AnnualSalesAmountIncludingVAT_LCY' => '1061.6900'
    'AnnualAmountPrimeCostLCY' => '934.9200'
    'Margin' => '126.7700'
    'CntWeekSale' => '33'
    'Trend' => '.9040'
    'NormTotal' => '36.0000'
    'NormOfAnalyst' => '8.0000'
    'UoM' => 'К-Т'
    'UnitsPerParcel' => '1.00000000000000000000'
    'OptimumMultipleness' => '1.00000000000000000000'
    'QtyPerCar' => '1'
    'FirstDate' => '2009-03-31'
    'LastDate' => '2017-04-26'
    'Unmarketable' => '0'
    'Discontinued' => '0'
    'BlockPurchase' => '0'
    'MinReservK1' => '2'
    'MinReservK2' => '2'
    'OnWay' => '0'
    'OrderQty' => '0'
    'Backorder' => '0'
    'Comment' => ''
    'Stock' => '23.0000'
]
```

However when I run a query in MS SQL Management Studio, column names are rendered correctly.

query:

```
SELECT 
                          [ItemKey]
                          ,[ItemNo]
                          ,[CompanyKey]
                          ,[Description]
                          ,[SearchDescription]
                          ,[TopCode]
                          ,[ResponsibleBrandAnalyst]
                          ,[ResponsibleBrandManager]
                          ,[Grp]
                          ,[SubGrp]
                          ,[Brand]
                          ,[V00214] , [ПТО0004]
                          ,[PrimeCost]
                          ,[UnitPriceD3]
                          ,[AnnualSalesQuantityBase]
                          ,[AnnualSalesAmountIncludingVAT_LCY]
                          ,[AnnualAmountPrimeCostLCY]
                          ,[Margin]
                          ,[CntWeekSale]
                          ,[Trend]
                          ,[NormTotal]
                          ,[NormOfAnalyst]
                          ,[UoM]
                          ,[UnitsPerParcel]
                          ,[OptimumMultipleness]
                          ,[QtyPerCar]
                          ,[FirstDate]
                          ,[LastDate]
                          ,[Unmarketable]
                          ,[Discontinued]
                          ,[BlockPurchase]
                          ,[MinReservK1]
                          ,[MinReservK2]
                          ,[OnWay]
                          ,[OrderQty]
                          ,[Backorder]
                          ,[Comment]
                          ,[Stock]

                    FROM 
                    (
                    SELECT [ItemKey]
                          ,i.[ItemNo]
                          ,i.[CompanyKey]
                          ,[Description]
                          ,[SearchDescription]
                          ,[TopCode]
                          ,i.[ResponsibleBrandAnalyst]
                          ,i.[ResponsibleBrandManager]
                          ,[Grp]
                          ,[SubGrp]
                          ,[Brand]
                          ,[p].[VendorNo]
                          ,[PrimeCost]
                          ,[UnitPriceD3]
                          ,[DirectBaseUnitCostEUR]
                          ,[AnnualSalesQuantityBase]
                          ,[AnnualSalesAmountIncludingVAT_LCY]
                          ,[AnnualAmountPrimeCostLCY]
                          ,[Margin]
                          ,[CntWeekSale]
                          ,[Trend]
                          ,[NormTotal]
                          ,[NormOfAnalyst]
                          ,[UoM]
                          ,[UnitsPerParcel]
                          ,[OptimumMultipleness]
                          ,[QtyPerCar]
                          ,[FirstDate]
                          ,[LastDate]
                          ,[Unmarketable]
                          ,[Discontinued]
                          ,[BlockPurchase]
                          ,[MinReservK1]
                          ,[MinReservK2]
                          ,[OnWay]
                          ,[OrderQty]
                          ,[Backorder]
                          ,[Comment]
                          ,[Stock] 
                    FROM [PM_Item] [i] 
                    INNER JOIN [PurchPrice] [p] ON p.ItemNo = i.ItemNo AND p.CompanyKey = i.CompanyKey 
                    WHERE i.ResponsibleBrandAnalyst = 'EES0947' AND i.Brand = 'BOSCH'
                    ) AS SourceTable
                    PIVOT
                    (
                     MAX([SourceTable].[DirectBaseUnitCostEUR])
                     FOR [SourceTable].[VendorNo] IN ( [V00214], [ПТО0004])
                    )  AS PivotTable
```

The `[ПТО0004]` column in incorrectly encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, declaring a character encoding as you did typically only affects the data, and not the column names. What version of driver are you using? This was a [known bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/138) that was fixed in 4.1.5, released earlier this year.